# Should you inherit an SFML RenderWindow into a custom render class, or have it as a field?

Tags: c++, sfml

After coding for some time in Java and using Graphics2d, I thought of using what I've learned in other languages, for example C++. I usually use SFML, and have a Render class so as to reduce dependency of other classes on SFML (as in, if I must switch libraries I would not need to switch much code in unrelated classes). I was wondering if I should have this Render class inherit RenderWindow, or simply have it as a member.

Comment: `RenderWindow` doesn't do any rendering. The drawing happens in `RenderTarget`. The `draw` method in `RenderTarget` is not virtual, so you cannot override it (you can mask it, but if you use polymorphism it won't work like you want it to). Also, I'm talking about SFML 2 here; I'm not sure about 1.6.

Comment: Interesting, but how should that affect my decision of inheritance vs field?

Answer (score 0):

A currently often suggested idiom is 'composition over inheritance'. From your vague description of what you're doing, it's actually impossible to give precise answer. I'm assuming you're talking about a simple interface between your framework and any graphics library.

In that case the answer is quite simple, because inheritance would automatically change the API of the render and it would change for every single graphics library you'd use and thus defeat the whole purpose of it. So if you use it as a member variable, you can craft a stable API for your framework and do all the adaption for different libraries within the scope of the render class.